# Getting last N rows of a table in ascending order without using a subquery, in pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I am trying to paginate some retrieved data by an amount of 10 per view. I was wondering how can I retrieve last N rows in ascending order of some timestamp column, without using a subquery? I don't want to use subquery because, I want to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to know the total number of rows in table, which were there without posing the limits.

The way I am doing it,

```
  SELECT * FROM (
             SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 10) temp
          ORDER BY ts ASC;
```

But seems that, it's not possible to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in the subquery, to know actual number of rows.

Comment: One could fetch the final 10 rows in *descending* order, and then reverse them within one's application code.  Or, alternatively, fetch the records and count with separate queries.

Comment: Why are you using the subquery. Running the subquery by itself should be perfectly all right.